# Using .prop() to disable/enable inline events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm working with a bit of preexisting js that needs some updates quickly. Ultimately my plan is to rewrite it to something less ugly, but in the meantime I have to try and work within what I have (time crunch).

I've seen several related threads throughout here but nothing that seemed to really speak to what I'm dealing with and, as a js amateur, some explanations may have been over my head. Thanks in advance for any assistance with this; I know there are similar questions out there but the responses either weren't quite making sense for me or simply didn't work when applied.

The basic gist is this:

I have an element that has a onmouseover and onmouseout inline event applied to it. I need to disable the onmouseover event on clicking the element and then reenable it when the user clicks outside of the element. This has proven more of a headache than I thought so I'm unsure at this point if it's plausible but hopefully the good people here can set me straight.

The JS:

```
function toggle_visibility(elem, id_one, id_two) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id_one);
        var f = document.getElementById(id_two);

        var $this = $(e);
        if ($this.data('mouseover') === true) {
          return;
        }

        $this.data('mouseover', true);
        if ($(e).hasClass('js-hide')) {
            $('[id^="group"]').addClass('js-hide').removeClass('js-show'); 
            $('.path-active').removeClass('path-active');          
            $(f).addClass('path-active');
            $(e).addClass('js-show');
            $(e).removeClass('js-hide');
        } 

    }

    function toggle_hidden(elem, id_one, id_two) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id_one);
        var f = document.getElementById(id_two);
        var $this = $(e);
        $this.data('mouseover', false);
        var timeOut = $this.data('timeout');

        if (typeof(timeOut) !== "undefined") {
          clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

        function timeoutFn(){             

            if ($(e).hasClass('ishover')) {
                timeOut = setTimeout(timeoutFn, 2000);
                $this.data('timeout', timeOut);
                return;
            } else if ($(g).data('clicked')) {
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
            }

            if ($(e).hasClass('js-show')) {
                $(e).addClass('js-hide');               
                $(e).removeClass('js-show');
            }
            if ($(f).hasClass('path-active')) {
                $(f).removeClass('path-active');
            }
         }

        var g = '[id^="overlay"]';

        var container = $(g);

        $(g).on('click', function() {
            $(g).data('clicked', true);
        });

        if ($(g).data('clicked')) {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        } else {
            timeOut = setTimeout(timeoutFn, 2000);
            $this.data('timeout', timeOut);
        }

    }

    function click_visibility(elem, id_one, id_two) {
        var g = '[id^="overlay"]';

        $(g).on('click', function() {                      
            $(g).prop('onmouseover', null);     
            $(g).data('clicked', true);
        });

        if ($(g).data('clicked')) {      
            $(document).on('click', function() {            
                $(g).prop('onmouseover', true);
                $(g).data('clicked', false);
                $(f).removeClass('path-active');
            });
        }
```

HTML example:

```
<g id="overlay-north-america" onclick="click_visibility(this, 'groupOne', 'north-america')" onmouseover="toggle_visibility(this, 'groupOne', 'north-america')" onmouseout="toggle_hidden(this, 'groupOne', 'north-america')">
    <g>
        <polygon class="st1" points="349.4,-0.1 347.8,4.9 373.4,4.8 363.8,11.3 347.8,22.3 349.4,25.5 344.6,27 344.6,35.2 335,38.4 
            335,43.3 315.7,43.3 317.6,46.1 303.2,46.4 299.8,51.1 291.7,51 291.7,60.7 279.1,60.7 280.6,55.9 274.3,55.9 274.3,46.1 
            269.5,44.8 274.3,41.3 274.3,30.4 280,29 279.1,19.1 256.5,17.4 255,14.5 248.3,12.7 250.2,17.2 238.7,17.4 238.7,24.1 
            243.5,24.1 243.5,30.4 248.3,29 248.3,38.5 255,38.5 253.2,43.3 259.8,43.3 256.5,46.3 248.3,46.4 250.2,51 243.5,52.8 
            243.5,75.3 248.3,77.2 248.3,104 242.1,104 240.6,99.4 235.8,99.4 232.4,104 229.1,107.4 200.2,108.9 200.2,118.4 197.3,118.5 
            197.3,115.5 189.2,113.6 189.2,118.4 185.8,118.5 185.8,128 181,128.1 181,137.8 165.1,137.7 168.4,142.6 171.4,147.5 
            161.7,155.5 161.7,165.2 166.5,170 165.1,178.1 176.2,178 176.2,184.4 185.8,183 185.8,187.8 195.4,187.9 195.4,192.6 
            173.2,190.7 173.2,185.8 168.4,185.9 166.5,189.3 160.3,190.7 160.3,187.8 163.6,181.1 160.3,181.1 158.8,174.8 145.9,176.1 
            149.2,169.7 150.5,152.3 137.7,152.3 136.3,156.9 118.4,157 118.4,160.4 112.1,161.8 113.6,187.8 125.2,187.8 125.2,176.4 
            142.5,176.4 142.5,181.1 137.7,181.1 137.7,192.6 132.9,194.1 145.9,197.3 147.3,214.7 160.3,216.7 155.4,224.4 144.4,224.4 
            136.1,214.9 134.7,206.9 120.3,205.3 120.3,200.3 101,202.1 101,195.5 91.4,197.5 91.4,189.3 86.6,189.3 86.6,174.6 83.1,171.5 
            78.5,176.3 77,171.6 65.5,171.6 67.4,161.8 62.6,160.4 62.6,139.5 52.9,139.5 54.4,118.5 67.4,102.6 77,102.5 77,94.6 62.6,84.9 
            62.6,76.9 67.4,76.9 68.8,65.5 64,65.5 60.7,62.5 44.9,60.6 46.2,64.3 33.7,65.7 33.7,70.2 20.7,70.3 15.9,75.2 -1.3,75.3 0,72.1 
            14.4,70.3 19.2,67.4 4.8,64.1 6.2,57.9 12.6,57.8 15.9,46.4 22.2,48.3 25.4,43.5 36.6,44.9 36.6,38.4 43.3,38.4 43.3,33.7 
            55.9,35.2 59.2,27 88.1,27 84.7,33.7 121.6,33.8 134.7,20.5 141,19.3 141,27 149.2,24.1 149.2,17.4 155.4,19.3 154,12.7 
            195.4,14.5 195.4,7.9 226.2,9.5 226.2,4.8 312.8,4.8 312.8,-0.1       "></polygon>
        <polygon class="st1" points="335,43.3 336.8,51.1 348,51 354.2,44.8      "></polygon>
    </g>
</g>


<div class="js-show" id="groupOne" onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('ishover')" onmouseover="$(this).addClass('ishover')">
<h5 class="divider divider-dark divider-sm">Jobs in North America</h5>

<ul class="list-unstyled spacing-none">
    <li><a class="text-hot no-decoration currentURL" href="#">List item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="text-hot no-decoration currentURL" href="#">List item 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="text-hot no-decoration currentURL" href="#">List item 3</a></li>
</ul>
<a class="padding-md-left padding-md-top text-reduced-md text-hot uppercase" href="#">... all jobs in north america</a></div>
```

Comment: What do you expect `$(g).prop('onmouseover', true);` to do? You need to set it to the Javascript string that you want to execute. Also, this should be `.attr` rather than `.prop`, but jQuery might fix that up for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I just ran across .prop today while trying to research this, so admittedly I don't have a good understanding of it  (thought it was merely reenabling the specified event). Afk at the moment but will try your suggestions and update the question as soon as I get the chance.